# How to capture the whole content of a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, screenshot, uiblureffect

I would like to capture the **whole content (not only the visible part)** of a scroll view. My idea is to use the method `[scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];`.

But, this method will capture only the visible part the scroll view?

**How can I access the whole content of a scroll view?**

---

PS: my final goal is to have a blurred version of my scroll view, to simulate a blurring effect when the scroll view goes under another view.